# Find optimal time schedule for nodes in a directed graph

Tags: graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

So I have a DAG representing a project and each node is a task, which has a variable that says how long it takes to finish that task.

We can assume that it is possible to work on any number of tasks at the same time.
How do I find optimal schedule of tasks so that I find a sequence of tasks that will result in earliest completion of the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can work on any number of tasks in parallel, then an optimal schedule can easily be computed. The starting time for a task in an optimal schedule can recursively be defined as the maximum of the optimal end times (i.e. optimal start time plus duration) of all its predecessor nodes in the graph. Tasks without predecessors all start at time 0 (or at whatever time you want them to start).

This recursion can be computed iteratively by iterating over the tasks in a topological order. In pseudocode, the algorithm could look like this:

```
// Computes optimal starttime for tasks in the dag.
// Input:  dag      : DAG with tasks as nodes
//         duration : Array with duration of tasks
// Output: Array with optimal starttime of tasks
def computeSchedule(dag, duration)
    starttime := [0 for each node in dag]
    for t in nodesInTopologicalOrder(dag):
        starttime[t] = max(starttime[p] + duration[p] for p in predecessors(t))
    return starttime
```